# select query on single column and display results in column wise mysql

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Here is a query i have and need to display results in column wise. But from this query i am getting all results in one column.

```
SELECT 
     ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT asn) 
         FROM table_name  
        WHERE 1=1 
          AND status IN('Failure','saved','Successful') 
          AND DATE(created_on) BETWEEN '20161020' AND '20161130'
     ) status
```

But i need result some thing like

```
Failure | saved | Successful
12           10         15
```

How can i acheive this ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) failure, SUM(CASE...)... FROM... GROUP BY...

Comment: @Strawberry pls use your hammer, provided the duplicate topic link

Comment: I have achieved this in the below way.

    SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT asn) FROM table_name  WHERE `status` = 'Failure' AND DATE(created_on) BETWEEN '20161020' AND '20161130') Failure,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT asn) FROM table_name   WHERE `status` = 'saved' AND DATE(created_on) BETWEEN '20161020' AND '20161130')  saved ,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT asn) FROM table_name  WHERE `status` = 'Successful' AND DATE(created_on) BETWEEN '20161020' AND '20161130') Successful

Is there any other better way to query this?

Comment: @Shadow Am I the only one with a hammer? How can that be?

Comment: Pivots are by their nature known to be ugly looking queries because you have to specify your data in an unnatural way in the query (and modify accordingly as your data for types/statuses/whatever change)

Comment: on another note, mysql community, please see Shadow's answers and try to reward him a few points every week ... he works tirelessly to call out dupes to help people :p